# PHP / Wordpress : category widget output

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Is there a way to modify wordpress category / archives widget html output without modifying wordpress core files? For example I have this output code:

```
<aside><h4>Title</h4><ul><li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="#">123</a> (1)</li></ul></aside>
```

And what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<aside><h4>Title</h4><ul><li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="#">123</a> <span class="number">[1]<span></li></ul></aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the filters `widget_categories_dropdown_args` and `widget_categories_args` to change the output for the Categories widget.
<sub>*Example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25002/12615*</sub>

And for the Archives widget, `widget_archives_dropdown_args` and `widget_archives_args`.
<sub>*Example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19945/12615*</sub>

Comment: can you please provide an example of how can I use it in order to achieve described above effect? I've read about widget_categories_args, but still don't know what parameters to modify.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Add spans around category counters 
*/
function _thz_filter_wp_list_categories($output, $args) {

    if($args['show_count']){
        $re = '/<\/a>(.*?)<\/li>/s';
        preg_match_all($re, $output, $matches);

        if(!empty($matches) && isset($matches[1])){
            foreach($matches[1] as $between){
                $between    = strip_tags($between);
                $output     = str_replace($between,'<span class="count">'.$between.'</span>',$output);
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', '_thz_filter_wp_list_categories',10,2 );

/*
 * Add spans around archive counters 
*/
function _thz_filter_get_archives_link( $output ) { 

    $re = '/<\/a>(.*?)<\/li>/s';
    preg_match_all($re, $output, $matches);

    if(!empty($matches) && isset($matches[1])){
        foreach($matches[1] as $between){
            $between = strip_tags($between);
            $output  = str_replace($between,'<span class="count">'.$between.'</span>',$output);
        }
    }

    return $output; 
}; 

add_filter( 'get_archives_link', '_thz_filter_get_archives_link', 10, 6 );
```